# Linkedin eventSubscription API is giving a 403 error

Tags: linkedin-api

I am using

PUT https://api.linkedin.com/v2/eventSubscriptions/(developerApplication:urn:li:developerApplication:{developer application ID},user:urn:li:user:{member ID},entity:urn:li:organization:{organization ID},eventType:ORGANIZATION_SOCIAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS)

Linkedin API with all the parameters intact. Each URN is encoded as urn:li:organization:12345 is encoded to urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A12345 but still getting a 403 Response.

Comment: #linkedin #linkedin-api

Comment: the message I am getting is : "Field Value validation failed in RESOURCE_KEY: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/key/developerApplication]"

Answer (score 1):

I think you forget to add this in headers :
X-Restli-Protocol-Version:2.0.0

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that there's a lot of missing/incorrect information in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-social-action-notifications?view=li-lms-2022-11&tabs=http#creating-and-updating-subscriptions). Since I'm working in go, here's how I finally got the url formatted correctly:

```
fmt.Sprintf(
    "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/eventSubscriptions/(developerApplication:%s,user:%s,entity:%s,eventType:ORGANIZATION_SOCIAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS)",
    url.QueryEscape(fmt.Sprintf("urn:li:developerApplication:%s", appId)),
    url.QueryEscape(fmt.Sprintf("urn:li:person:%s", userId)),
    url.QueryEscape(fmt.Sprintf("urn:li:organization:%s", organizationID)),
)
```

The breakdown:

- The URNs, and *only* the URNs, need to be urlencoded.

  - Not the surrounding parentheses
  - Not the commas
  - Not the colons preceding the URNs (`developerApplication:`, `user:`, and `entity:`)
- Your PUT request needs to include the `X-Restli-Protocol-Version` header and `Authorization` header
- If, for some reason, you use the `/rest/eventSubscriptions/` url instead of `/v2/eventSubscriptions/`, you also need to include the `LinkedIn-Version` header
- The `appId` is *not* your app's client id, but instead the numeric id you see in the app settings url in the linkedin developer portal (i.e. `https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps/<appId>/auth`)
- The URN structure in the docs is wrong: you need to use `urn:li:person:<userId>`, not `urn:li:user:<userId>`

Answer (score 0):

The application id is actually a numeric field in the url when you visit your application settings, put that value instead of the client id.